# How to find the best fit path

Tags: graph-theory, dijkstra

I have a set *X* of ordered weightings e.g. [2, 8, 5, 13, 1].

I am given a graph with edges of various weights. [Example graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MYSn.png)

Given a start node, which algorithm should be used to find the path such that the weightings of the path are best fit with the weightings of set *X*?

Is there a smarter way of doing it bar iterating over every possible path of length *length(set X)* and seeing which one is best fit?

**What do I mean by 'best fit'?**
In my mind it means that the overall absolute difference between the weights of the edges of the path and the corresponding weights of set X will be as small as possible.

Comment: Hi! Awesome question. Could you please clarify whether the order of the list matters or whether the algorithm is allowed to reorder it?

Comment: This looks like an assignment problem. You must assign each index in the list to an edge in the graph, so as to minimise the differences between the list values and the edge values, under the constraint that the edges must form a path.

Comment: Hi Stef, the order of the list does matter, so the path must traverse the graph, starting at the chosen 'start' node, such that the weightings of the path are as best a fit to that in set X.

Comment: I should add that the weightings of consecutive edges can be added in order to fit the next index of the set X weightings. For example, if the start node was the top-left node in the example graph, and set X was [9, 8, 2 ...], a possible path would be: starting at top-left node, going along edge of weight 3, going along edge of weight 6 (3+6=9 so good fit), going to far-right node of weight 8, and so on...

Comment: I think I'm coming to the conclusion that you would have to consider every conceivable path of length length(set X) to find the answer.

Comment: Is the path allowed to use a vertex more than once?

Comment: Yes, but for any given node n in the path, there must be at least two subsequent different nodes before node n is revisited.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to explain what is a "best fit" in your problem? Thanks.

Comment: *"What do I mean by 'best fit'? In my mind it means that the overall absolute difference between the weights of the edges of the path and the corresponding weights of set X will be as small as possible."* Note that there are several, non-equivalent, ways to define "best fit". For instance, instead of minimising the sum of absolute differences, you could want to minimise the sum of squared differences. Intuitively, both those formulations go in the same direction, but it is easy to construct a graph and a set X for which those two are not equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

First, if the order of the list of weights is important, then it's a list, not a set.

You could use a best-first search. Just not directly in your given graph, but in a graph you'll build from it. I'm gonna assume the graph is directed. If not, just make the edges both ways.

Let's call `N` the length of your list `X`. Then, let's define `N` replicates of your input graph `G[0]`, `G[1]`, ... `G[N-1]`.

Then, let's define the weights of the edges in `G[i]` such that it corresponds to the cost of matching `X[i]` (the i-th weight) to that edge. So basically, if in the initial graph `G` an edge had the weight `w`, then in `G[i]` it will have a cost `|w-X[i]|`.

Finally, connect the graphs `G[i]` to `G[i+1]` (the next graph) such that when a weight of `X` has been matched, we *move up one graph*. So basically, if we have an edge `(v1[i], v2[i])` in the graph `G[i]` with weight `w`, now we move it so that we have an edge `(v1[i], v2[i+1])` with the same weight `w`. Essentially, instead of staying on the same level, we move up level up.

In this new graph you can apply you usual shortest-path algorithms. Including Dijkstra since all your weights are non-negative. The complexity is bounded by that of your choosen shortest path algorithm in a graph `N` times larger.

But note that you don't have to explicitely represent the `N` replicates of the graph. Especially since you may have noticed that a good chunk of your new graph cannot be used at all. You could simply consider your graph implicitly by representing the nodes by the pair `(V, i)` with `V` a node in the original graph, and `i` the current position in your weight list `X`.

You could replace your notion of *best fit* by whatever you want as long as it ends up as a sum along the path. And you can use Dijkstra only as long as you don't generate negative edge weights.

Comment: This method does not consider the constraint (unfortunately only mentioned in a comment) that "for any given node n in the path, there must be at least two subsequent different nodes before node n is revisited". It seems this could be handled by extending the state from `(v, i)` to `(v, i, p, q)` where `p` and `q` are the last two visited nodes, `(v, i, p, q)` is missing connections to `p` and `q` and going from `(v, i, p, q)` to a vertex `w` gives `(w, i+1, q, v)`.

Comment: This is always possible. But it makes the size of the graph grow really fast. The larger the graph, the less likely the algorithm will reuse computations and the closer it gets to an exhaustive search of all the path.